# What sort of Python array would this be? Does it already exist in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a numpy array:

```
m = array([[4, 0, 9, 0],
          [0, 7, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 5]])
```

The 4 columns of m are labelled:

```
c = array([ 10, 20, 30, 40])
```

I want to be able to slice an object `o` such that:

```
o.vals[0,:] = array([4, 9])
o.vals[1,:] = array([7,])
o.vals[2,:] = array([])
o.vals[3,:] = array([5])
o.cols[0,:] = array([10, 30] )# the non-zero column labels from row 0
o.cols[1,:] = array([20,])
o.cols[2,:] = array([])
o.cols[3,:] = array([40])
```

Is there an existing Python object that would let me do this?

I have looked at [Scipy Sparse Matrices](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html), but it isn't quite what I am looking for.

**AN UPDATE on 17th August 2015:** I have had a play around with some ideas and came up with this, which is almost the same as what I described last week:

- https://github.com/jsphon/NumericalFunctions/blob/master/jagged_array/JaggedKeyValueArray.rst
- https://github.com/jsphon/NumericalFunctions/blob/master/jagged_array/jagged_key_value_array.py

Answer (score 3):

You can get close to what you want by defining a class to contain `m` and `c`:

```
import numpy as np

class O(object):
    def __init__(self, m, c):
        self.m, self.c = m, c

    def vals(self, i):
        return self.m[i][self.m[i]!=0]

    def cols(self, i):
        return self.c[self.m[i]!=0]


m = np.array([[4, 0, 9, 0],
          [0, 7, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 5]])

c = np.array([ 10, 20, 30, 40])

o = O(m, c)

for i in range(4):
    print 'o.vals({0:d}) = {1}'.format(i, o.vals(i))
for i in range(4):
    print 'o.cols({0:d}) = {1}'.format(i, o.cols(i))
```

Returns:

```
o.vals(0) = [4 9]
o.vals(1) = [7]
o.vals(2) = []
o.vals(3) = [5]
o.cols(0) = [10 30]
o.cols(1) = [20]
o.cols(2) = []
o.cols(3) = [40]
```

(It might be easier to use the indexing, `m[i][m[i]!=0` and `c[m[i]!=0]` directly, though.)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `pandas` (http://pandas.pydata.org/). (since you tried `scipy/numpy` which are not standard library Python packages I assume it is ok to suggest another package).

A `DataFrame` is an object that lets you do all of your operations, and many more.

```
import numpy as np                                                                
import pandas as pd                                                               

m = array([[4, 0, 9, 0], [0, 7, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 5]])               

# create a dataframe                                                                                  
df = pd.DataFrame(m, columns=[10,20,30,40])   

# replace 0 with NaN (to make use of pandas `dropna`)                                    
df.replace(0, np.NaN, inplace=True)

# values per row                                                                  
df.irow(0).dropna().as_matrix()                                                   
array([ 4.,  9.])                                                                 

df.irow(1).dropna().as_matrix()                                                   
array([ 7.])                                                                      

df2.irow(2).dropna().as_matrix()                                                  
array([], dtype=float64)

# column labels (as list)                                                         
df.irow(1).dropna().index.tolist()
[10, 30]

# or non-zero values per column?
df.icol(0).dropna().as_matrix()
array([ 4.])

# ...
```

You could also combine column label and value, since the normal return from the `dropna` is a DataFrame.

```
non_zero_1 = df.irow(0).dropna()
labels_1 = non_zero_1.index

Int64Index([10, 30], dtype='int64')
```

Best just try Pandas and see if it fits your needs. And also have a look at the great intro (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can get close to what you want with a CSR sparse matrix:

```
import scipy.sparse as sps

m_csr = sps.csr_matrix(m)
```

You could now implement functions similar to what you are after like this:

```
def vals(sps_mat, row):
    row_slice = slice(sps_mat.indptr[row], sps_mat.indptr[row+1])
    return sps_mat.data[row_slice]

def cols(sps_mat, col_labels, row):
    col_labels = np.asarray(col_labels)
    row_slice = slice(sps_mat.indptr[row], sps_mat.indptr[row+1])
    return col_labels[sps_mat.indices[row_slice]]
```

Using this functions we get:

```
>>> for row in range(m_csr.shape[0]):
...     print vals(m_csr, row)
...
[4 9]
[7]
[]
[5]

>>> for row in range(m_csr.shape[0]):
...     print cols(m_csr, [10, 20, 30, 40], row)
...
[10 30]
[20]
[]
[40]
```

This will be very efficient on large matrices, although the syntax is not quite what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nested class and overload the `__getitem__` attribute of your objects :

```
import numpy as np

class indexer:
   def __init__(self,arr):
      self.arr=arr
      self.d=self.caldict(self.arr)
      self.vals=self.values(self.arr,self.d)
      self.cols=self.columns(self.d)

   def caldict(self,arr,dd={}):
      inds=np.array(np.nonzero(arr)).T
      for i,j in inds:
          dd.setdefault(i,[]).append(j)
      return dd
   class values:
        def __init__(self,arr,d):
           self.arr=arr
           self.d=d

        def __getitem__(self,index):
          try:
            return self.arr.take(index,axis=0)[self.d[index]]
          except KeyError:
            return []
   class columns:
        def __init__(self,d):
           self.d=d
           self.c=np.array([ 10, 20, 30, 40])

        def __getitem__(self,index):
          try:
             return self.c.take(self.d[index])
          except KeyError:
             return []
```

Demo:

```
m=np.array([[4, 0, 9, 0],
       [0, 7, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 5]])

o=indexer(m)
print o.vals[0],'\n',o.vals[1],'\n',o.vals[2],'\n',o.vals[3]
print '------------------'
print o.cols[0],'\n',o.cols[1],'\n',o.cols[2],'\n',o.cols[3]

[4 9] 
[7] 
[] 
[5]
------------------
[10 30] 
[20] 
[] 
[40]
```